# Retrieve value from query string?

Tags: jsp, jstl

How can I retrieve the value of a Query String Parameter using Expression Language in a JSP?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<c:out value = "${pageContext.request.queryString}" />
```

update:

If you want certain value for example ?key1=val1&key2=val2

then

```
<c:out value = "${param.key1}" />

<c:out value = "${param.key2}" />
```

Comment: I will return whole query string,but i want specific value by name.

Comment: Hi Thansks.I tried above approach,it returns empty string. alert('<c:out value = "${param.key1}" />');